# How to navigate in view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For example 3 View controllers A,B,C.
I can navigate from A to B & to C.But my question how to navigate from C to A directly by pressing back button?

Comment: Read about push & pop. [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need this `UINavigationController` method:

[-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a)